# How do I send the selected value of a drop down menu to an email in django

Tags: python, django

I have this site where the user can fill out a form and when they hit submit all the results of the form get sent to me in an email. All the parts of the form get sent except for their choice from a drop down menu. Does anyone know where I went wrong in my code?
Here is my forms.py

```
    CONDOS=[
        ('silvermountaincondo', 'Silver Mountain Condo'),
        ('redhillcondo', 'Red Hill Condo'),
        ('lakesidecondo', 'Lakeside Condo'),
        ('pointeplacecondo', 'Pointe PLace Condo'),
        ('rhodesviewcondo', 'Rhodes View Condo'),
]

class ContactForm(forms.Form):
        contact_name = forms.CharField(required=True, label='Full name')
        contact_email = forms.EmailField(required=True, label='Email Address')
        contact_phone = forms.CharField(required=True, label='Phone number')
        condo = forms.ChoiceField(required=True, label='Which condo would you like to reserve?', choices=CONDOS)
        arrival_date = forms.DateField(required=True, help_text='Please enter your arrival date (YYYY-MM-DD)')
        departure_date = forms.DateField(required=True, help_text='Please choose your departure date (YYYY-MM-DD)')
```

Here is my views.py

```
def contact(request):
    form_class = ContactForm

    if request.method =='POST':
            form = form_class(data=request.POST)

            if form.is_valid():
                    contact_name = request.POST.get('contact_name', '')
                    contact_email = request.POST.get('contact_email','')
                    contact_phone = request.POST.get('contact_phone','')
                    condo = request.POST.getlist('condo','')
                    arrival_date = request.POST.get('arrival_date','')
                    departure_date = request.POST.get('departure_date','')

                    template = get_template('contact_template.txt')
                    content = template.render({
                            'contact_name': contact_name,
                            'contact_email': contact_email,
                            'contact_phone': contact_phone,
                            'condo': condo,
                            'arrival_date': arrival_date,
                            'departure_date': departure_date,
                    })
                    send_mail(
                            "New Booking from vacationcondos.vegas",
                            content,
                            "www.vacationcondos.vegas" + '',
                            ['email@gmail.com'],
                            #headers = {'Reply-To': contact_email}
                    )
                    return redirect('Properties/contact')

    return render(request, 'Properties/contact.html', {
            'form': form_class,
    })
```

This is an example of what the email looks like

Contact Name: John Smith

Email: johnsmith@gmail.com

Contact Phone Number: 5555555555

Arrival date: 2017-07-30

Departure date: 2017-08-13

In between the phone number and arrival date it should print the condo that was selected from the drop down list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your views.py file, the line `condo = request.POST.getlist('condo','')` should be replaced with `condo = request.POST.get('condo','')` since you are using a [ChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/fields/#choicefield) instead of a [MultipleChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/fields/#multiplechoicefield).  This should then place the correct choice for `condo` in your email.